# How do you write good highly useful general purpose libraries?

Tags: api

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291212/why-is-microsoft-source-code-so-complex) about Microsoft .NET Libraries and the complexity of its source code.  From what I'm reading, writing general purpose libraries and writing applications can be two different things.  When writing libraries, you have to think about the client who could literally be everyone (supposing I release the library for use in the general public).

What kind of practices or theories or techniques are useful when learning to write libraries?  Where do you learn to write code like the one in the .NET library?  This looks like a "black art" which I don't know too much about.

Answer (score 9):

That's a pretty subjective question, but here's on objective answer. The [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613) book (be sure to get the 2nd edition) is a very good book about how to write effective class libraries. The content is very good and the often dissenting annotations are thought-provoking. Every shop should have a copy of this book available.

Comment: Absolutely correct. The book tells you how you should create highly reusable frameworks.

Answer (score 6):

You definitely need to watch Josh Bloch in his presentation [How to Design a Good API & Why it Matters](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/effective-api-design) (1h 9m long). He is a Java guru but library design and object orientation are universal.

Answer (score 5):

One piece of advice often ignored by library authors is to internalize costs.  If something is hard to do, the library should do it.  Too often I've seen the authors of a library push something hard onto the consumers of the API rather than solving it themselves.  Instead, look for the hardest things and make sure the library does them or at least makes them very easy.

Answer (score 4):

I will be paraphrasing from [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201924889) by Scott Meyers, which I have found to be the best advice I got:

> Adhere to the **principle of least astonishment**: strive to provide classes whose operators and functions have a natural syntax and an intuitive semantics. Preserve consistency with the behavior of the built-in types: when in doubt, do as the ints do.
>
> Recognize that anything somebody can do, they will do. They'll throw exceptions, they'll assign objects to themselves, they'll use objects before giving them values, they'll give objects values and never use them, they'll give them huge values, they'll give them tiny values, they'll give them null values. In general, if it will compile, somebody will do it. As a result, **make your classes easy to use correctly and hard to use incorrectly**. Accept that clients will make mistakes, and design your classes so you can prevent, detect, or correct such errors.
>
> Strive for **portable code**. It's not much harder to write portable programs than to write unportable ones, and only rarely will the difference in performance be significant enough to justify unportable constructs.
>
> Even programs designed for custom hardware often end up being ported, because stock hardware generally achieves an equivalent level of performance within a few years. Writing portable code allows you to switch platforms easily, to enlarge your client base, and to brag about supporting open systems. It also makes it easier to recover if you bet wrong in the operating system sweepstakes.
>
> Design your code so that **when changes are necessary, the impact is localized**. Encapsulate as much as you can; make implementation details private.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: I just noticed I *very nearly* duplicated [**what cherouvim had posted**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291870/how-do-you-write-good-highly-useful-general-purpose-libraries/1291913#1291913); sorry about that! But turns out we're linking to different speeches by Bloch, even if the subject is exactly the same. (cherouvim linked to a December 2005 talk, I to January 2007 one.) Well, I'll leave this answer here — you're probably best off by watching *both* and seeing how his message and way of presenting it has evolved :)

---

FWIW, I'd like to point to this Google Tech Talk by [Joshua Bloch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch), who is a greatly respected guy in the Java world, and someone who has given speeches and written extensively on API design. (Oh, and designed some exceptionally good general purpose libraries, like the Java Collections Framework!)

> Joshua Bloch, Google Tech Talks, January 24, 2007:
>   "[**How To Design A Good API and Why it
>   Matters**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAb7hSCtvGw)"  (the video is about 1 hour long)

You can also read many of the same ideas in his article [Bumper-Sticker API Design](http://www.infoq.com/articles/API-Design-Joshua-Bloch) (but I still recommend watching the presentation!)

(Seeing you come from the .NET side, I hope you don't let his Java background get in the way too much :-) This really is  *not* Java-specific for the most part.)

Edit: Here's another [1½ minute bit of wisdom](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ni_KEkHfto#t=47m42s)  by Josh Bloch on why writing libraries is hard, and why it's still worth putting effort in it (economies of scale) — in a response to a question wondering, basically, "how hard can it be". (Part of a presentation about the Google Collections library, which is also totally worth watching, but more Java-centric.)

Answer (score 2):

Krzysztof Cwalina's blog is a good starting place.  His book, Framework Design Guidelines: Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for Reusable .NET Libraries, is probably the definitive work for .NET library design best practices.

http://blogs.msdn.com/kcwalina/

Answer (score 2):

The number one rule is to treat API design just like UI design: gather information about how your users really use your UI/API, what they find helpful and what gets in their way. Use that information to improve the design.  Start with users who can put up with API churn and gradually stabilize the API as it matures.

I wrote a few notes about what I've learned about API design here: http://www.natpryce.com/articles/000732.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd start looking more into design patterns. You'll probably not going to find much use for some of them, but as you get deeper into your library design the patterns will become more applicable. I'd also pick up a copy of NDepend - a great code measuring utility which may help you decouple things better. You can use .NET libraries as an example, but, personally, i don't find them to be great design examples mostly due to their complexities. Also, start looking at some open source projects to see how they're layered and structured.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of separate points:

The .NET Framework isn't a class library. It's a *Framework*. It's a set of types meant to not only provide functionality, but to be extended by your own code. For instance, it does provide you with the `Stream` abstract class, and with concrete implementations like the `NetworkStream` class, but it also provides you the `WebRequest` class and the means to extend it, so that `WebRequest.Create("myschema://host/more")` can produce an instance of your own class deriving from `WebRequest`, which can have its own `GetResponse` method returning its own class derived from `WebResponse`, such that calling `GetResponseStream` will return your own class derived from `Stream`!

And your callers will not need to know this is going on behind the scenes!

---

A separate point is that for most developers, creating a reusable library is not, and should not be the goal. The goal should be to write the code necessary to meet requirements. In the process, reusable code may be found. In that case, it should be refactored out into a separate library, where it can be reused in the future.

I go further than that (when permitted). I will usually wait until I find two pieces of code that actually do the same thing, or which overlap. Presumably both pieces of code have passed all their unit tests. I will then factor out the common code into a separate class library and run all the unit tests again. Assuming that they still pass, I've begun the creation of some reusable code that works (since the unit tests still pass).

This is in contrast to a lesson I learned in school, when the result of an entire project was a beautiful reusable library - with no code to reuse it.

(Of course, I'm sure it would have worked if any code *had* used it...)